# What's the effect of having different connectionFactories on JmsComponent, JmsTransactionManager, JmsConfiguration etc

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

If we have this:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="config" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="nonPooledConnectionFactory"/>        
</bean>

<bean id="myComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="config"/>       // Which one is used?
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>   // Which one is used?
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
</bean>
```

Which connectionfactory would be used in a camelroute that uses "myComponent"??
It's transactionmanager references a pooled connnectionfactory, but it's configuration references a non-pooled connectionfactory.

We can set a connectionFactory on so many levels: txManager, JmsComponent, Configuration etc.  Wonder which rule is used for disambiguation if the given one is different?

Answer (score 0):

Spring will wire up whatever it finds...  If there's an ambiguity, the application context will not start without adding 'primary' distinction to one instance.

Comment: The context starts just fine.

Comment: Then there's no ambiguity in your configuration.  That said, you may run into odd issues given that the JmsComponent is using two different connection factories.  Spring won't do the semantic analysis to catch that kind of thing...